# Go to page and clear the stack [Xamarin Forms]

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have navigation stack like this:

Page1 -> Page2 -> Page3 -> Page4 -> Page5 -> Page6

And I want to Navigate TO **Page2** FROM **Page6** and clear rest of pages (Page3, Page4, Page5)

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which type of navigation do you have and what have you tried?

Comment: I have NavigationService where I use PushAsync and PopAsync

Comment: So you have a Hierarchical Navigation. What have you tried to achieve the required behaviour?

Comment: I have tried remove page after page from stack until i get Page2, but maybe there is better solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Not a built-in method that you could use. You will have to clean the navigation stack yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to navigate back a count of pages, you need to remove *count* pages from the navigation stack:

```
for (var i = 1; i < countPagesToRemove; i++)
{
    Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
}
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```