# Remove multiple pages from stack- xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app which has several screens. The navigation of my pages is like this.

1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6

The 6th page is popup created using Rg.plugin.popup.User can navigate to and forth as many times in this hierarchy. But when they reach 6th page there is a button. In the button click  it should navigate user to 2nd page. How can I remove all the pages ie; 3,4,5 from stack and go to 2nd page.

**What I tried**

on button click :

```
for (var i = 1; i < countPagesToRemove; i++)
{
    Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
}
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857611/go-to-page-and-clear-the-stack-xamarin-forms) ask same question but it doesn't work for me.

**Then I tried like this**

```
await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new NCDashboard());
```

It will navigate to 2nd page but will not show back button to first page due to nothing in the stack. So how can I solve this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I tried to call the first option from popup. ie; the 6 th page

Comment: @AndroDevil The code you tried on button click, works well on navigate from one page to another page with `Navigation.PushAsync`. I would do some test with `Rg.plugin.popup` and feedback ASAP.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I amlittel confused about the parameter "countPagesToRemove". What will be this parameter?

Comment: in your case, you want to remove 3 pages, so: var countPagesToRemove = 3

Comment: @AndroDevil I post the code i test on GitHub. https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/Navigation_Page The screenshot: https://imgur.com/17IalYA

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Bro I tried this code on rg.plugin.popup . But it only popasync the popup> Not navigating to 2 page

Comment: @AndroDevil I am doing the test for this plugin, and would feedback ASAP.

Comment: the problem is that you call the first option from the 6th page, which is a PopupPage. RG.Popups pages doesn't go into the same stack as your regular pages. You need to call it from page which sits on the same navigation stack as the other pages or you need to get reference to that shared navigation stack in the 6th page.

Comment: @Reed so how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling RemovePage from the 6th page, which is Rg.Popups PopupPage. As we've discussed in the comments, Rg.Popups PopupPage doesn't go onto the same stack as regular Xamarin.Forms pages. You need to get reference to the stack where the pages from 1st to 5th sits and execute RemovePage on it. Try out the following workaround:

```
    var mainPage = (Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage);
    for (var i = 1; i < countPagesToRemove; i++)
    {

     mainPage.Navigation.RemovePage(mainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[mainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
    }
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

The code on Page6 works well.

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]);
        }
    }
    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                    
        await PopupNavigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Bro thanks for the reply. In my case the 6th page is only Rg.Popup. All other pages are normal pages.

Comment: I think you should try this solution as well. If it works as expected, it would be a better solution since it doesn't make assumptions about the type of Application.Current.MainPage